# Why is there no negative sign in the linear form calculation of voltage but there is a negative in the integral form?

Tags: electric-fields, potential, voltage, conventions

The formula for voltage given $\vec{E}$ and $d$ is $$V = |\vec{E}| d.\tag{1}$$

However, the formula is also $$V = - \int \vec{E} \cdot dr. \tag{2}$$

Why does one of these formulas have a negative and one not have a negative? It seems that the first formula should just be derived from the second one by assuming that you are going in a straight line. But then why does the negative get lost?

Edit:
I forgot to do the absolute value of $\vec{E}$ in the first formula.

Comment: where did you find this formula? http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/electric/efromv.html gives the negative sign to dV, not V.

Comment: The first formula, as written, equates a scalar to a vector. I think you need something like  $\Delta V= \vec E. \vec d$ (though I'd include a negative sign because if a positive test charge is displaced in the direction of the field, it loses potential energy).

Comment: "... $V = \vec{E} d$..." One side of this equation is a scalar and the other side is a vector. This is not possible.

Comment: This is a question about correcting your own typos, not a physics question.

Comment: @hft Sorry, I forgot to take the magnitude (or do the dot product if they are pointing in the same direction): $V = |\vec{E}| \cdot d$. Thanks for the comment, I updated the post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The minus is a reminder of the convention used in electrostatics.  When $\nabla \times \vec{E}=0$, $\vec{E}$ is the gradient of a potential and by convention $\vec{E} = -\nabla \phi$.  If $\gamma$ is a path from point $1$ to point $2$, integrating over $\gamma$ gives
$$-\int_{1}^{2} \vec{E}\cdot d\vec{r} = \int_{1}^{2} \nabla \phi \cdot d\vec{r} = \phi(2)-\phi(1)$$
and this value does not depend on the path $\gamma$, only on the endpoints.  When $\vec{E}$ is tangent to $\gamma$ in the same direction, the integral is over a negative quantity, so the voltage drops from a higher value at point $1$ to a lower value at point $2$.

In the general case of electrodynamics where $\nabla\times\vec{E}$ is not necessarily zero, the integral between two points may depend on the path $\gamma$, but the minus sign is there to remind us that voltage drops when travelling along a path the same direction as $\vec{E}$.

The equation $V=\|\vec{E}\|d$ is just a special case of the integral for a straight line and a uniform field along the line, but it neglects to remind us that voltage drops in the direction of the field.

Comment: Thanks so much! I really appreciate the answer, and the part about the curl is quite interesting.